# C# LINQ - convert nested dictionary to a list

Tags: c#, linq

How do I flatten a nested dictionary into a list of some objects (`SomeObject` in the following example) which should hold keys of those dictionaries?

For example: let's have a dictionary of the following type

```
var nestedDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>();
```

then, let's have this class

```
public class SomeObject
{
   public int var1;
   public int var2;
   public string someStringVar;
}
```

How do I convert `nestedDictionary` to a `List<SomeObject>` where `var1` is the key of the outer dictionary, `var2` is the key of the inner dictionary and `someStringVar` is the string value of the inner dictionary?

Essentially, how do I transfer this:

```
nestedDict[0][0] = "foo";
nestedDict[0][1] = "bar";
nestedDict[0][2] = "foo1";
nestedDict[1][0] = "bar1";
nestedDict[1][1] = "foo2";
nestedDict[1][2] = "bar2";
```

to this (in pseudo C# just to visualize it)

```
objList[0] = SomeObject { var1 = 0, var2 = 0, someStringVar = "foo" }
objList[1] = SomeObject { var1 = 0, var2 = 1, someStringVar = "bar" }
objList[2] = SomeObject { var1 = 0, var2 = 2, someStringVar = "foo1" }
objList[3] = SomeObject { var1 = 1, var2 = 0, someStringVar = "bar1" }
objList[4] = SomeObject { var1 = 1, var2 = 1, someStringVar = "foo2" }
objList[5] = SomeObject { var1 = 1, var2 = 2, someStringVar = "bar2" }
```

using LINQ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
var flattened =
from kvpOuter in nestedDictionary
from kvpInner in kvpOuter.Value
select new SomeObject()
{
    var1 = kvpOuter.Key,
    var2 = kvpInner.Key,
    someStringVar = kvpInner.Value
};
var list = flattened.ToList(); // if you need a list...
```

Comment: Seems that I just tend to overcomplicate things when working with LINQ...I just wasn't able to see such simple solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you!!! Wow I was ready to bang my head against the wall, but now it all seems ok and I can keep coding forever!

Comment: How would you do this using LINQ if you just wanted the nested dictionary returned as a list? Without the Object initializer?

Comment: @JWiley: do you want to turn each nested dictionary into a list (so finally obtaining a list of lists), or you want to get a final list containing all the keys-values in the inner dictionary ? You can't simply remove the object initializer from the code above, you need to return something for each inner dictionary element (e.g. kvpInner)...

Comment: list of lists, I ended up doing `.Values.SelectMany(x => x).ToList()`. Is there a better way?

Comment: @JWiley: actually with your code you'll get a list of key-value pairs, not a list of lists...

Comment: oh, how could I change that to list of lists? I'm mainly concerned with getting it readable for JSON

Comment: (Note: I will abbreviate KeyValuePair with KVP)
`nestedDict.Values.Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList()` will create a `List<List<KVP<int,string>>`, but if you want to include also the outer dictionary keys: `nestedDict.Select(x => new KVP<int, List<KVP<int, string>>>(x.Key, x.Value.ToList())).ToList()`. BTW, json.net library can serialize/deserialize the nested dictionary without any problem...

Answer (score 11):

You can use [SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) and write something like:

```
var objList = nestedDictionary.SelectMany(
    pair => pair.Value.Select(
        innerPair => new SomeObject() {
            var1 = pair.Key,
            var2 = innerPair.Key,
            someStringVar = innerPair.Value
        })).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 `SelectMany` is where i tend to use query  syntax (if possible), don't know why. If it's formatted so nicely, method syntax is just as well readable(in C# unlike VB).

Comment: @Tim, not that there's anything wrong with it :) I actually chose method syntax because of the `ToList()` call at the end (I don't like mixing query syntax with a final method call for some reason).

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an enumerable of `IEnumerable<SomeObject>`:

```
var results = from d in nestedDictionary
              from innerD in d.Value
              select new SomeObject { var1 = d.Key, var2 = innerD .Key, someStringVar = innerD .Value };
```

Call `results.ToList` or `results.ToArray` to get either a `List<SomeObject>` or `SomeObject[]` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xxx = nestedDictionary.SelectMany(
                    kvp =>
                    kvp.Value.Select(
                        xx => new SomeObject() {var1 = kvp.Key, var2 = xx.Key, someStringVar = xx.Value}));
```